# K[$\alpha$]/K is algebraic

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have to prove that: If $\alpha \in E$ and $E/K$ is a field extension and $\alpha$ is algebraic over $K$ then $K[\alpha]/K$ is algebraic, but I do not know how to use the hypothesis to do this. Can you help me to prove it? thank you :).

Comment: I have tried to saying that for hypothesis there is an f(x) in K[x] such that f evaluated in alpha is zero, but I do not know how this could imply that   K[α]/K  is algebraic :)

Comment: Your assumption is that $\alpha$ is algebraic over $K$, and you are required to prove that $K[\alpha]$ is algebraic over $K$. This means that every $\beta \in K[\alpha]$ is algebraic over $K$, not just $\alpha$. However, the simplest proof won't focus on the element $\beta$ directly, since $\beta$ could be some complicated polynomial expression of $\alpha$. Instead, it will use the fact that $\beta$ is algebraic over $K$ if and only if $K[\beta]$ is a finite-dimensional $K$-vector space. Think about how you might prove that this condition holds.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : If $p(\alpha) \in K[\alpha]$, you are looking for a polynomial equation for $p(\alpha)$, i.e. a polynomial $q(X) \in K[X]$ such that $q(p(\alpha)) = 0$. Try to show that $p(\alpha)^n$ is equal to some "low-degree" polynomial in $\alpha$.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Thank you @PatrickDaSilva I will do my attempt with this and then I tell what happened :)

Comment: Patrick, thank you but is this the only thing I need to do, Should I prove that $p(\alpha)^{n}$ has coeficients in $K$? or that is because $p(x) \in K[x]$

Comment: $K[\alpha]$ is the ring of polynomials in $\alpha$ with coefficients in $K$ modulo some ideal. Of course $p(\alpha)^n$ has coefficients in $K$! How could it not? I don't see what you want to prove here. What is your issue?

Comment: I am sorry @PatrickDaSilva yes you are right but I get confused because $p(\alpha)$ is a number and you are telling me that I must show that it can factors in some lower degree polynomial in alpha. Can you tell me your point please :)

Comment: @user162343 : It's definitely not a number, it's an element of $K[\alpha]$. $K$ is a field, but you don't know more about it ; a field can be made of other stuff than numbers. 

Anyway, if you want to see numbers, take the example of the field extension $\mathbb R[i]/\mathbb R$ where $i^2 = -1$. Then if you take a polynomial in $i$, then if $n \ge 2$, 
$$
p(i) = \sum_{j=0}^n a_j i^j = a_n i^n + \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} a_j i^j = -a_n i^{n-2} + \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} a_j i^j
$$
so that by induction on $n$ any polynomial expression in the number $i$ can be reduced to a polynomial of degree $\le 1$.

Comment: You just need to do this argument in "full generality".